# How to Solve the following Sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

$\sum_{i=1}^{80} (3^i+3\times 2^i)$

I tried plugging in $i = 1$, and got $9$ as the output, following the same procedure, plugging in $i=2$ gave me $21$. I took note of $21/9$, but noticed the 3rd term divided by the second term $(51/21)$ did not give the same ratio, so somehow this is not a arithmetic or geometric series? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for formula of  the geometric series

Comment: Like I said, I can't find a common ratio, I don't know what 'r' is

Comment: It is sum of 2 geometric series, one with $r=2$ and the other $r=3$

Comment: Okay I get it now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{80}\left( 3^i + 3\times2^i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{80}3^i + 3\sum_{i=1}^{80}2^i$$

So the series has been split into the sum of two geometric series which you can tackle with the standard tactic and combine to get your answer.

Comment: So 'r' would be 3 in the first ratio, and 2 in the second? Plugging these numbers into two seperate formulas, then summing them to get the final answer?

Comment: Exactly! (making sure to multiply by that 3 for the second series when you calculate your final answer)

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  Write out several terms of a sum on x^i.  Now multiply that by 1-x and see what happens when you cancel terms.  (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +...+x^N)(1 - x).  Lots of terms will cancel, but there will be terms a 1 and a x^(N+1) that don't cancel.

Comment: You should have used LaTeX, but I don't see why you deserved any downvote for this answer, so I've upvoted. It seems recently there are a number of people who hate correct and beautiful mathematics and prefer wrong and beggarly school-syllabus...

Comment: @user21820  Brother, you are so right. There has been a lot of trolling and bitchiness on this site lately.